# WPF custom button

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I start to learn `WPF` and there is something that is still unclear for me:

i created new Style for `button`:

```
<!-- no border button style -->
<Style x:Key="NoBorderButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />            
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="false" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So this is my button:

```
<Button Content="Button"  Style="{StaticResource NoBorderButton}">

</Button>
```

Now after search for solution to remove all the border i found this `template` that need to be add to the `button`:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

So i have several questions:

1. What this `template` doing ?
2. Why i cannot add it the the `style` i created inside my `Windows.Resources` ?

Comment: What you will find is the some controls don't honor some properties.  In Button I think BorderThickness is hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer your questions directly, however there is much that can be discussed here.

> What this template doing?

All controls have some kind of default template, a pre-defined *look and feel* of what the control *looks like*.

The `Template` is overriding the default *look and feel* for your `Button`. What you are effectively doing is completely starting afresh a new template for a button.

So for example, you can define a new template for what a button would *look like*. It can be a `TextBlock` inside an `Ellipse` for example. Instead of the default button template.

It's hard to put into words, but I think I explained that well enough.

> Why i cannot add it the the style i created inside my Windows.Resources?

You can:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```